# Where can one go to get a hard cover book bound?

Tags: self-publishing, process

I wrote many stories/books in my past...but I do not have the resources to bind and glue/print pages for a book. Where may I go to do that? or Where can I get the resources to do this on my own?

Comment: If you can't find a local print shop to do it, get onto your nearest university. At least in the past in the UK, theses had to be hard bound. Some one had to do it.

Comment: Where abouts are you, geography wise? Do you live near a Staples or a Rymans?

Comment: staples i live near staples

Comment: I don't wanna post an answer in the comments and the stackexchange app doesn't like me so I can't realLy make an answer tonight but ... If it helps I specified those two companies purposefully :P

Comment: Hopefully, you haven't proofread in the past and will be hiring a good one. Try "I have written..." I'm not a grammar nazi, but this is a writing site.

Comment: @TheThom Is your contention that because this is a writing site that all writing here should be grammatically correct? To me it seems that English isn't the OPs first language, and maybe what he has written is not written in English. Besides, I'm sure I'm not alone in having a very different writing style here than I do when I'm writing creatively. My language usage is very dependent upon the intended audience. P.S. I'm not a grammar pacifist.

Comment: @MichaelB Went back and forth about whether to say anything. If the OP's not a native English speaker then someone needs to teach her. Certainly style is different based on audience, but writers should avoid the most egregious of the grammar rules in all cases except when quoting a character. I will never pick on someone on this site for not full sentences or subject/verb agreement. Anyway, it was a judgment call and I weighed in. Sorry for any offense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Lulu](https://www.lulu.com/) gets the most recommendations, I've noticed. I think you can buy individual printed copies or bulk orders.

Comment: Looks professional. How do you actually get a book cover to be hard bound though with just the average printer/

Comment: Ah I misunderstood. If you mean like binding the book yourself at home I'd say you should research websites from people who do it as a hobby. Any craft store should have the right glue and other materials for binding, you probably just need to clamp the pages down until they dry. Sounds like a lot of work though.

Comment: Agreed, it also takes a much greater amount of energy and patience

Answer (score 2):

As @yblehS says, Lulu is probably your best bet.

I have a book published with Lulu in hard cover and they do a nice, professional job. They have no minimum size on an order so if you just want a handful of copies -- or 1 copy -- that's no problem.

You could buy the equipment to professionally bind a book at home for like a couple of thousand dollars. Unless you're planning to print hundreds or thousands of copies, that's unlikely to be worth the investment.

I'm sure you could come up with a craft-shop approach to it, cut the pages yourself and glue them and make a cover out of cardboard and laminate it and all. But that sounds like a lot of work when Lulu will do it for like ten or fifteen bucks and probably do a better job than you could.

Not hard cover, but: I used to struggle to find an appointment calendar in a format I like every year. Now I make my own. I create a PDF file, send it off to CreateSpace, and order 2 copies. It costs me like $10. CreateSpace doesn't do hardcover, which brings us back to Lulu.